# Decommissioning Exchange Server 2003 box?

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange-2003

I wonder what is the final or proper steps that you need to do in order to successfully decommission the old Exchange Server 2003 from AD?

At the moment I have successfully migrated Exchange Server 2003 into 2007 and mail is working fine.

However when I run Get-ExchangeServer it is still there but without role assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [this](http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/migration-deployment/removing-last-exchange-2003-server-exchange-2007-part1.html)?

Answer (score 1):

This is the procedure suggested by Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822931

Comment: thanks for your reply man, why the article is titled "How to remove the first Exchange Server 2003 computer from the administrative group" ? while this is my last E2k3 or at least I just want to make sure that it is decommissioned properly from the AD database.